# How to draw rich text with Skia or SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, xamarin, skia, skiasharp

I want to draw rich text like iOS's Attributed Text or Xamarin.Forms's `FormattedString` with **SkiaSharp**, but I can't find how to.

I found the `DrawText` method, but it's for simple text rendering with one color and one font. No mixed colors and/or fonts and no styles like bold, italic, strike-through, or underline.

Do I have to do it with my own rich text rendering logic?

Answer (score 22):

This is doable using the `SKPaint` type. Basically, as you draw, you set the properties on the paint:

```
var paint = new SKPaint();
paint.StrikeThruText = true;
paint.TextSize = 24;
paint.Color = SKColors.Yellow;
paint.UnderlineText = true;
paint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName(
    "Arial", 
    SKFontStyleWeight.Bold, 
    SKFontStyleWidth.Normal, 
    SKFontStyleSlant.Italic);
```

and then you can draw:

```
canvas.DrawText("Fancy Text", 30, 30, paint);
```

I hope this helps!

For other effects, you can use the `SKShader` and `SKMaskFilter` types. This does a blur:

```
path.MaskFilter = SKMaskFilter.CreateBlur(SKBlurStyle.Normal, 5);
```

**EDIT**

After some time, it seems we actually have a much better way to draw text - and not just the basic underlines. I would whole-heartedly recommend this library by Brad Robinson: https://github.com/toptensoftware/RichTextKit

I mean, just look at that beautiful thing!

[image: RichTextKit]

Comment: SKPaint.UnderlineText does not exist anymore. Is there a replacement?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/81abc43e6f0b1a789e1bf116820c8ede68d778ab/gm/texteffects.cpp#L97) is an example that can be ported for your purposes. Or just draw lines below/through if you don't need to be "fancy".

Comment: Skia's API changes every month. I really admire people who are able to use this library and are willing to learn it from the source code.